# How to use data attributes in React

Tags: reactjs

How to use data attributes in React without using quotes (quotes in this case make code less readable)?

```js
const e = React.createElement;

e(
  "span", {
    id: "foo",
    className: "bar",
    "data-tippy-content": "tooltip",
  }, "Foobar"),
```

... and without using JSX.

Comment: You can't. Object keys must be either quoted or valid JS [identifiers](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Identifier). `data-tippy-content` is a subtraction, as far as JS is concerned.

Comment: I was hoping something like `dataSet` was available. https://github.com/facebook/react/issues/1259

Answer (score 2):

Since you're already not using JSX, you could write a wrapper for `React.createElement` that transforms `dataset: {...}` into `data-` attributes:

```
const e = (tag, attrs, children) => {
  const { dataset, ...otherAttrs } = attrs;
  if (dataset) {
    for (const key in dataset) {
      otherAttrs[`data-${key}`] = dataset[key];
    }
  }
  return React.createElement(tag, otherAttrs, children);
};

e("h1", {dataset: {"tippy-content": "foo"}}, ...);
```